# Is is.subset not working in R?

Tags: r, arules

```
require(arules)
Groceries <- read.transactions("C:/Users/IBM_ADMIN/Desktopgroceries.csv",sep=",")

 m1 <- apriori(Groceries,parameter=list(support=0.007,confidence=0.25,minlen=2))

subset.matrix <- is.subset(m1, m1)
```

#this piece of line is not working

This produces the following error message:

```
Error in match(x, table, nomatch = 0L) : 
  'match' requires vector arguments
```

Please do help me.

Comment: Your question does not contain a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/4303162). It is therefore hard to understand your problem and give you an appropriate answer. Please make your data available (e.g. by using `dput()`) or use one of the example data sets in R. Also, add the minimal code required to reproduce your problem to your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`apriori` returns rules object, not a vector:

```
data("Adult")
## Mine association rules.
rules <- apriori(Adult, 
    parameter = list(supp = 0.5, conf = 0.9, target = "rules"))
class(rules)
# [1] "rules"
```

if you want to compare lists of rules you will need to transform this object to a data.frame, e.g.:

```
rules.df <- as(rules, "data.frame")
is.subset(rules.df$rules, rules.df$rules)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Bulat. My query is now resolved. But i have got another query. The following piece of code is not working: subset.matrix <- is.subset(rules.df$rules, rules.df$rules)     subset.matrix[lower.tri(subset.matrix, diag=T)] <- NA
redundant <- colSums(subset.matrix, na.rm=T) >= 1

Comment: you need to find out from which module `is.subset` function that you are using.

Comment: Hi Bulat, i used 'rje' package but especially the last line "redundant <- colSums(subset.matrix, na.rm=T) >= 1" does not execute.

Comment: Can you raise another question here on so for the new issue.